# What is the most efficient way to use Active Record to select one random record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, random

Say I have 100,000 Tweets. How can I use active record to very efficiently select just one Tweet?

```
Tweet.all => [100K Records]

I want => Tweet.find_by_id[random] (something like this)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid selecting all and just build random into your query, something like this:

`Tweet.find(:first, :order => "RAND()")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this
`Tweet.first(:order => "RAND()")`

Comment: yours has more style than Jed